# What is the meaning of しちゃ?

Tags: translation, parsing, contractions

> ダメだよ喧嘩ばかりしちゃ
> you can't keep getting into fights like that

What does しちゃ mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

～ちゃ is an informal abbreviation of ～ては, so しちゃ is from しては.  This sentence is just rearranged so the conclusion is first, but has the same meaning "forward"

> 喧嘩ばかりしてはダメだよ

(Where ～てはダメ means "*(do/have)ing ～ is no good"*)